# An erroneous subquery working in few conditions & fails in others?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tokudb

Following two queries are exactly same, except the country name. In Query 1 its 'Malaysia' & in Query 2 its 'India'.

The query itself is erroneous; Since I am using "`ac.country`" in first subquery whereas i actually needed to use "`ass.country`", but still i am getting result in Query 1 whereas I get NULL in Query 2.

Can someone explain why this is happening.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DATE(DAY) AS daycust,
            (SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS webss 
            FROM ACQ AS ass
            WHERE ass.day = ac.day 
            AND ac.country IN (SELECT DISTINCT aam.country_name FROM accounts AS aam)
            AND country =  'Malaysia') AS webss

FROM analytics_country AS ac

WHERE DAY BETWEEN  '2016-07-01' AND  '2016-08-02'
             AND ac.country IN (SELECT DISTINCT aam.country_name FROM accounts AS aam)
             AND country =  'Malaysia'

GROUP BY daycust
ORDER BY daycust
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DATE(DAY) AS daycust,
            (SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS webss 
            FROM ACQ AS ass
            WHERE ass.day = ac.day 
            AND ac.country IN (SELECT DISTINCT aam.country_name FROM accounts AS aam)
            AND country =  'India') AS webss

FROM analytics_country AS ac

WHERE DAY BETWEEN  '2016-07-01' AND  '2016-08-02'
             AND ac.country IN (SELECT DISTINCT aam.country_name FROM accounts AS aam)
             AND country =  'India'

GROUP BY daycust
ORDER BY daycust
```

Note : I would also like to add that the output varies across different versions of MySql.

```
In Server version: "5.5.30-tokudb-7.0.1-MariaDB-log" -> Both the queries work fine.

In Server version: "5.5.41-tokudb-7.5.5-MariaDB - MariaDB Server" -> Only Query 1 works fine.
```

Comment: Turn the `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN`.  It will probably work faster, and possibly work 'correctly'.

Comment: Elaborate on what goes wrong with Query 2.  "NULL" -- as in one row with NULLs?  Or what?

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` from each version.